# Passing managed object from app delegate to a VC that is not RootVC

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a Navigation Controller who's initial view is a View Controller with a button that does a push segue to a tableviewcontroller. I'm wanting to pass the managed object context from the appdelegate to the tableviewcontroller.

I'm using a storyboard with a layout like so:

(Navigation Controller > ViewController) > TableviewController

I tried referencing the tableviewcontroller by using the array of view controllers held in the navigation controller. But the navigation controller is only saying it has 1 VC.  (not 2)

Do I first have to pass it to the initial VC and then pass it from the initial VC to the tableVC using prepare for segue?

What is the most practical way of passing the managed object context from the app delegate to a view controller that is not the root view controller?  I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you answered your own question -- passing it to the first controller then the table view controller is as good a way as any. You could get a reference to the app delegate from your table view controller, and grab it from there, but I don't don't think that's any better really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your AppDelegate has a reference to this 'Navigation Controller' the you can use:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate= (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.navigation.tableObject = ..
```

otherwise you need to pass that vc from your navigation down to your UITableviewController.